# Expo xde is not launching on centOS?

Tags: linux, react-native, centos, expo

I download the Expo Ide(.AppImage) from official site

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/installation.html

of expo and followed the following instructions:

```
chmod a+x xde*.AppImage
./xde*.AppImage
```

but I am not able to launch a the xde on my system.

I have restarted all my development environment.

Answer (score 0):

the * sign refers to your specific version. Replace the * for the numbers there. For instance,

```
chmod a+x xde-2.22.1-x86_64.AppImage
./xde-2.22.1-x86_64.AppImage
```